# Наложить linear-gradient на иконку fontawesome

Tags: html, css

Добавляю linear-gradient , но меняется bg, Т.к указываю bg, можно ли как-то добавить linear-gradient в саму иконку?

Comment: можно увидеть ваш код!

Answer (score 1):

**background-clip**

```css
i.fa {
  font-size: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```